# Please help me with a sentence in someone's lyrics

Tags: sentence-structure, grammaticality-in-context

I came across a web site and the web site was playing an American band's song.

Here is the lyric that makes me confused:

> I wanna know have you ever seen the rain?

I am wondering why the singer wrote this sentence, is it grammatical?
And I am wondering Why it was not written this way:

> I wanna know if you have you ever seen the rain?

Comment: It's a song lyric. Those make their own kind of sense, not subject to grammar or syntax rules.

Comment: Please, read the question before you vote to close?  Kitty isn't asking what it *means*, she's asking about the *grammar* of the lyric.  It may be a duplicate but it's not off-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, John Fogerty.  The sentence is a statement, as if he's speaking to you:

> "I want to know -- have you ever seen the rain?"

As a kind of "direct quote", there are many possible structures that might not *seem* grammatical in a written sentence, but which are fine:

> "Tell me, what's your favorite color?"
>
> "I should tell you, don't always believe what you read"

Comment: @kitty  of course this is separate from what he actually *means* -- which, I have to confess, I never understood.  What do you think he means?

Answer (score 2):

It's a song, and most songs have to rhythm with the beat, so the writers try to fit a lyric that will rhythm with the beat, therefore:

> I wanna know if you have ever seen the rain?

may sound better than

> I wanna know have you ever seen the rain?

However, the sentence sounds good grammatically, the writter just forgot to add one ***comma*** between *know* and *have*, which will function as a  separation of two clauses - One affirmative - The other questionable.

If the song writter intended to ask if they had ever seen the rain, so:

> I wanna know, have you ever seen the rain?